# How to know my API server URL? with Flask and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have made an API server with Flask, and I want to host this with AWS. I have already created an EC2 Instance. How can I find the URL of this API server? Of course, I also made an SSH connection.

Comment: Do you use elastic beanstaslk to run the flask app on AWS?

Comment: no. I'm using a free tier product. (t2.micro) with Ubuntu

Comment: Please do some research before asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public IP and the public DNS / URL for your instance are in EC2 console, as shown in the screenshot:

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=Newest&tagMode=Watched]

Comment: Thanks for the help. It would have been really hard if it weren't for you